# Text selection inside inline-blocks without space between

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textselection

I have a problem with text selection in Chrome. I have two spans styled as inline-blocks (same happens with divs). When I try to double click text inside one of the blocks all neighbor blocks are selected.

It can be solved by putting at least one space or newline between blocks. But that space will become visible and will break layout.

Demonstration (in Chrome 58):

[image: Double click demo]

Firefox works fine for both cases.

How to solve it without making mess out of the markup?

Source code:

```css
span {
  outline: 1px solid red;  
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<span>Apple</span><span>Orange</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Lemon</span> <span>Pear</span>
```

Comment: I have found one "messy" solution, putting such a span between each two spans will do the job: `<span style="max-width: 0px;min-width: 0px;">&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: floats are out of the question?

Comment: @zgood I would prefer not to use them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of a normal space, you can use a [Zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

**Edit**: ..or an element with `font-size: 0` containing a normal space.

```css
span {
  outline: 1px solid red;  
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<span>Apple</span><span>Orange</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Lemon</span>&#8203;<span>Pear</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Lemon2</span><i style="font-size:0;"> </i><span>Pear2</span>
```

Comment: It looks quite good. But if a user decides to select both spans the invisible space will be copied too and can make problems somewhere else.

Comment: That's true. A shorter version of your "messy" solution is to add a space with `font-size: 0` between the elements. I have updated my example code.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it....

try adding this:

`user-select: all;`

so it would be this:

```css
span {
  outline: 1px solid red;  
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<span>Apple</span><span>Orange</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Lemon</span> <span>Pear</span>
```

Comment: Not very good as clicking just once selects the whole word breaking the normal behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```css
span {
  outline: 1px solid red;  
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<span>Apple</span><span>Orange</span>
   
<br/>
<span>Lemon</span> <span>Pear</span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).